# Word/expression for inclination toward using disadvantageous tools

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What is the best word/expression to describe a phenomenon or tool that, despite its disadvantages, is used by people? In fact, there are some alternatives for them, however, there is a weird inclination toward them.

As an example, *smoking* is a good one that most of people know its harms and probably its alternatives, however do not give it up.

**Update:**

As another more specific example, take Microsoft Office. There are several (probably more powerful) [alternatives](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/best-microsoft-office-alternatives/) for that, however, remarkable numbers of users are still using MS Office. Is it only a habit?

Comment: An example could improve your question!

Comment: @Josh61, Of course, for example _smoking_.

Comment: You may include this and other possible examples in your question.

Comment: Usually it's a *habit*.

Comment: @Zikato, So, how to describe this bad and harmful habit with a specific phrase/word?

Comment: An addiction, a stupidity or lack of responsibility?

Comment: Addiction to smoking is not a weird inclination to some sort of **tool** but a nasty habit of **substance** abuse. Weird inclination to tools that are inferior to alternatives is a totally different question, and could be due to any of a plethora of reasons, such as familiarity, nostalgia, stubbornness, laziness, adversity to change...

Comment: @user21820, It's just only an example.

Comment: @Eilia: Yes I know, but if you want to include too many things, then there is no answer to your question except very vague terms like "bad/odd habit". Presumably you have some very specific situation in mind and you'll have to tell us what it is otherwise we'd be guessing in the dark.

Comment: MS Office use is really more about "Market saturation" than about people opting for the lesser product. Most people don't realize there are other options out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by tools you mean commercial products (like your MS Office example), consider:

**Brand loyalty** <sub>[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/brand-loyalty.asp), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_loyalty)</sub>

> Brand loyalty is a result of consumer behavior and is affected by a person's preferences. Loyal customers will consistently purchase products from their preferred brands, regardless of convenience or price.

For instance,

- He keeps buying Samsung phones even after better alternatives have emerged; out of brand loyalty.

---

For cases other than that of commercial products, you could consider proverbs like...

**there's no accounting for taste**

- "I love working at weekends." "Well, there's no accounting for taste!" (From [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/there-s-no-accounting-for-taste))

**to each his own / each to his own**

- I keep telling him that car is the better and more comfortable way to commute, but he keeps using his motorcycle. Well, to each his own.

**one man's meat is another man's poison**

These expressions are a litte broader than your requirements, in that they cover a person's preference to something with no obvious disadvantage (like color). They're applicable, nonetheless.

PS - Your smoking example is a poor one. That's obviously a case of addiction/substance abuse, as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The word used in this context is most likely 'vice'. It's pretty well-attested too when talking about bad habits.

The Cambridge Online even gives an example sentence that is similar to the first example you've given.

> vice noun (FAULT)
>
> C2 [C or U] a moral fault or weakness in someone's character: Greed,
>   pride, envy, and lust are considered to be vices. mainly humorous My
>   one real vice (= bad habit) is chocolate.